# How can I define a custom equality operation that will be used by immutable Set comparison methods

Tags: scala, set, overriding

I have an immutable Set of a class, Set[MyClass], and I want to use the Set methods intersect and diff, but I want them to test for equality using my custom equals method, rather than default object equality test

I have tried overriding the == operator, but it isn't being used.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The intersect method is a concrete value member of GenSetLike

spec: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenSetLike.html
src: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/GenSetLike.scala#L1

```
def intersect(that: GenSet[A]): Repr = this filter that
```

so the intersection is done using the filter method.

Yet another Edit:

filter is defined in TraversableLike

spec: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html

src: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L1

```
def filter(p: A => Boolean): Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
      for (x <- this) 
        if (p(x)) b += x
      b.result
}
```

What's unclear to me is what it uses when invoked without a predicate, p. That's not an implicit parameter.

Comment: Have you tried just overriding .equals?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

equals and hashCode are provided automatically in case class only if you do not define them.

```
case class MyClass(val name: String) {
  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case that: MyClass => that.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = name.toUpperCase.hashCode
}

Set(MyClass("xx"), MyClass("XY"), MyClass("xX"))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[MyClass] = Set(MyClass(xx), MyClass(XY))
```

If what you want is reference equality, still write equals and hashCode, to prevent automatic generation, and call the version from AnyRef

```
  override def equals(o: Any) = super.equals(o)
  override def hashCode = super.hashCode
```

With that:

```
Set(MyClass("x"), MyClass("x"))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[MyClass] = Set(MyClass(x), MyClass(x))
```

You cannot override the `==(o: Any)` from AnyRef, which is sealed and always calls equals. If you tried defining a new (overloaded) `==(m: MyClass)`, it is not the one that `Set` calls, so it is useless here and quite dangerous in general.

As for the call to `filter`, the reason it works is that `Set[A]` is a `Function[A, Boolean]`. And yes, `equals` is used, you will see that function implementation (`apply`) is a synonymous for `contains`, and  most implementations of `Set` use `==` in contains (`SortedSet` uses the `Ordering` instead).  And `==` calls `equals`.

---

Note: the implementation of my first `equals` is quick and dirty and probably bad if MyClass is to be subclassed . If so, you should at the very least check type equality (`this.getClass == that.getClass`) or better define a `canEqual` method (you may read [this blog](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/06/equality-scala.html) by Daniel Sobral)

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Both answers were correct, but I selected this one as it provides a full explanation.

Comment: No, not *my* blog! Chapter 28 on [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html) dies a much better job.

Comment: Sorry, I will try not do it again ;-)

Comment: Small note: It's chapter 30 on the second edition of Programming in Scala

Comment: What if my class is not a case class?

Comment: Same. The point was that as case class generates Equals/hashCode automatically, one may believe that you cannot have your own.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to override `.hashCode` as well. This is almost always the case when you override `.equals`, as `.hashCode` is often used as a cheaper pre-check for `.equals`; any two objects which are equal **must** have identical hash codes. I'm guessing you're using objects whose default `hashCode` does not respect this property with respect to your custom equality, and  the Set implementation is making assumptions based on the hash codes (and so never even calling your equality operation).

See the Scala docs for `Any.equals` and `Any.hashCode`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Any.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out a potentially critical point. This is case class.

I implemented the change you recommended, but it doesn't have any effect.

For case classes:

The equals method is automatically redefined to compare two instances of the same case class structurally rather than by identity.
The hashCode method is automatically redefined to use the hashCodes of constructor arguments.

Comment: In addition, is .equals even used for the comparison in these methods? From the src it appears filter is used on the Set, with some unknown predicate.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer shows a custom mutable Set with user-defined Equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739432/how-to-implement-a-set-with-a-user-defined-equality). It could be made immutable by replacing the internal store with a `Vector` and returning a modified copy of itself upon each operation

Answer (score 0):

"It is not possible to override == directly, as it is defined as a final method in class Any. That is, Scala treats == as if were defined as follows in class Any:

```
    final def == (that: Any): Boolean =
      if (null eq this) {null eq that} else {this equals that}
```

" from Programming In Scala, Second Edition