# Assertion for overloaded equality operator fails for triple-equals but passes for double-equals

Tags: scala, scalatest, assertion, case-class

I overloaded a case class's equality operator:

```
case class Polygon(points: Seq[(Double, Double)]) extends Shape {
  def ==(that: Polygon): Boolean = { ... }
}
```

My unit tests pass when using double-equals in assertions:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class ShapeSpec extends FunSpec {
  describe("Polygon") {
    it("is equal to all its rotations") {
      val p = Polygon(Seq( ... ))
      for { i ← 0 until p.points.size } {
        val q = Polygon(p.points.drop(i) ++ p.points.take(i))
        assert(p == q)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when using === instead of ==, the same tests fail:

```
[info] Polygon
[info] - is equal to all its rotations *** FAILED ***
[info]   Polygon(List((-1.0,-1.0), (4.0,-1.0), (4.0,2.0), (1.0,2.0),
         (1.0,1.0), (-1.0,1.0))) did not equal PolygonM(List((4.0,-1.0),
         (4.0,2.0), (1.0,2.0), (1.0,1.0), (-1.0,1.0), (-1.0,-1.0)))
         (ShapeSpec.scala:28)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: because `===` uses [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) method automatically generated for your case class

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681183/how-can-i-define-a-custom-equality-operation-that-will-be-used-by-immutable-set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spelled it wrong. ;)

It should be:

```
override def equals(x: Any): Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks! For reference, I found [this article](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html) which explicitly states that the way I was doing it is “an utterly wrong definition of equals.”