# Scala set element uniqueness: What to implement for comparison of user defined classes?

Tags: scala, set, compare, unique

I am trying to find this information in the [Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Set) but it looks like it is not there.

In the case of Java this was dependent of the `Set` implementation that was used, AFAIK. In some cases the method to implement was `equals`, in the case of a `HashSet` the comparison was done with the hash method.

The actual implementation details of `scala.collections.mutable.Set` seem to be unspecified, as the implementation may vary (and that's nice, I like my code to be generic), but I wonder how can I ensure specific comparisons are done with such a generic collection.

For example, in the case of [`SortedSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.SortedSet) there is an implicit `Ordering[A]` to ensure the order. Is there *anything* similar in the case of `Set`?

Comment: Also, is there any way to use the documentation in a better way so that I may not need to ask for such questions? Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I define a custom equality operation that will be used by immutable Set comparison methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681183/how-can-i-define-a-custom-equality-operation-that-will-be-used-by-immutable-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both scala and java require you to implement both equals and hashCode in a consistent way. If it worked with just one in some cases it's coincidental. You must have both so that with your class being X, for every X, `x1.equals(x2) == (x1.hashCode() == x2.hashCode())`.

Scala case classes have equals and hashCode methods implemented by the compiler for you.

Comment: I see, and the documentation about `Set` and other specific classes says nothing because these methods should be (are) defined for *every class*, right?

Comment: @Trylks They should be defined on every class which you ever intend to compare for equality or insert into a map or set.

Comment: Technically they already are, the compiler doesn't raise any errors. As far as I could see, it is impossible to not have them defined.

Comment: They are implemented, but the implementation is often not useful. It's simply the object identity for equals (same instance), and for hashCode it uses the object's memory address.