# Define equality/ordering implicitly for collections

Tags: scala, collections, equality, implicit

Is it possible to define my own notion of equality or ordering for the collections in Scala? Overriding `equals` and `hashCode` doesn't work in this case because I'd like to have more than one instance.

**Here is roughly what I had in mind:** (ignore the invalidity of this code)

```
implicit val customEq1(x: Int, y: Int) = x % 8 == y % 8
val customEq2(x: Int, y: Int) = x.toString == y.toString.take(2)

val union = Set(1,15,3).union(Set(3,7,8)) // => Set(1,3,8)
```

I'd imagine equality/ordering being a typeclass, but the functions like e.g. `diff`, `union`, `intersect` don't seem to offer any such functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define a custom equality operation that will be used by immutable Set comparison methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681183/how-can-i-define-a-custom-equality-operation-that-will-be-used-by-immutable-set)

Comment: The answers to the "duplicate" question suggest overriding `equals` which is not what I wanted, as explained in my question.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple different implementations for comparison, you can create a class for each with the appropriate overrides, then coerce the type of the set with implicit conversion, something like this:

```
class MyCompInt { overrides... }
val union = Set[MyCompInt](1, 15, 3).union(...)
```